# Symbols "T _Z20" before exported function

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, nm

Trying to find why client application can't find exported function in .so library I have done. I did

```
nm -D libmylib.so |grep " T " |grep aaa
```

and got answer:

```
T _Z20aaasPP8CashInfoPiS1_S2_S2_PcS3_
```

If I look to other functions that are visible to client app I have output without `T _Z20` symbols at the beginning and trailing garbage like `PP8CashInfoPiS1_S2_S2_PcS3_`.

What does `T _Z20` means and why my new function is not visible to client application?

Comment: They are C++ mangled names.

Comment: https://demangler.com/. Yours seems to indicate a name of 20 characters, though, when `aaas` is only 4.

Comment: Add the `-C` option to the `nm` command to to see the unmangled function names.

Comment: Read: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage